# HTML not displaying within <div>

Tags: html, model-view-controller

Good day,

I am busy building a feature content scroller for news. IT is working very nice. But I do have one problem. The news I'm getting, I'm sending that to a table then I use that to show in my scroller. But when there is HTML inside that text I'm returning it does not read that HTML and I need it to show because it is an image.

The text I'm returning in my div must be able to read the HTML

```
>  Knights captain Theunis de Bruyn has been included as a new cap in
> the Proteas Test squad against Sri Lanka.<br/><a
> href='http://ewn.co.za/2016/12/14/our-depth-is-improving-says-csa-s-linda-zondi'><img
> src='http://cdn.primedia.co.za/primedia-broadcasting/image/upload/c_fill,h_289,w_463/iqe1gj6jqlonxix9055t'
> /></a>
```

Working with a MVC view, inside that view, I have  where I add the news article. The article I get from a table in my DB. Sometimes the article has Html inside where the is an img tag with a link to get me the img. But when I run my application and the article shows it show everything in normal text and does not see the HTML that was returned.

Comment: Hi! I could not understand you question. Can you make the context more clear to understand better?

Comment: Working with a MVC view, inside that view, I have <div> where I add the news article. The article I get from a table in my DB. Sometimes the article has Html inside where the is an img tag with a link to get me the img. But when I run my application and the article shows it show everything in normal text and does not see the HTML that was returned.

Comment: You can use `Html.Raw`

Comment: @anon using `Html.Raw` thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Html.Raw` allows me to see the HTML within my `<div>`